# Wordpress site not loading css correctly in Chrome (ignoring media queries)

Tags: css, wordpress, google-chrome

I'm working on a test website in wordpress that displays fine in firefox and edge, but not Chrome, specifically the tabbed headers and the responsive design (Chrome isn't reading the media queries in the style.css file at all for some reason). I've validated the code I have access to and I'm still having a discrepancy.

**The website in question:**

http://alessiosrestaurant.ashleywalters.net/

Curiously, I've done a static page which isn't using wordpresses code and it shows up fine on Chrome, using the same styles below. It seems to be when I integrate the two that the issues appear.

**The static version:**

http://alessiosrestaurant.ashleywalters.net/wp-content/themes/Frank-master/index2.html

**Pertinent screenshots:** 
[firefox vs chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MgFQ.jpg)

**>>Corresponding code below<<**

header.php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Frank
 */
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 7 | IE 8]>
<html class="ie" lang="en-US">
<![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9) | !(IE)]><!-->
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">


    <title>
        <?php
        wp_title( '&mdash;', true, 'right' );
        bloginfo( 'name' );
        ?>
    </title>

    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>" />
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pragati+Narrow" rel="stylesheet">

    <?php if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' ); ?>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>
<body id="page" <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <div class="chromeframe">Your browser is out of date. Please <a href="http://browsehappy.com/">upgrade your browser </a> or <a href="http://www.google.com/chromeframe/?redirect=true">install Google Chrome Frame</a>.</div>
    <![endif]-->
 <header class="header">
  <h1>Alessio's</h1>
  <nav>
   <ul>
    <li class="first"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li ><a href="#">The Food</a>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="#">Pizza</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Catering</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">The People</a>
     <ul>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
     </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="arrow">Order Online</a></li>
   </ul>
  </nav>
  <ul id="social">
   <li><a href="#"><img alt="image" src="wp-content/themes/Frank-master/images/twitter.svg" /></a>
   <li><a href="#"><img alt="image" src="wp-content/themes/Frank-master/images/facebook.svg" /></a>
   <li><a href="#"><img alt="image" src="wp-content/themes/Frank-master/images/instagram.svg" /></a>
  </ul>
 </header> <!-- End Banner -->
```

style.css (the only stylesheet used for the main styles):

```
/*
Theme Name:     Frank
Theme URI:      http://somerandomdude.com/work/frank
Description:    The next step of the Franklin Street theme.
Author:         P.J. Onori, heavily altered by Ashley Walters
Author URI:     http://somerandomdude.com/hello/
Version:        0.9.3
License:                GPL 3.0
License URI:        http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html
Tags:                   brown, red, white, two-columns, fixed-width, sticky-post, custom-menu
*/


/* ------------------------*/ /* ---------->>> Style Resets <<<-----------*/ /* ------------------------*/
/* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
   v2.0 | 20110126
   License: none (public domain)
*/
* { 
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}

ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none; 
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
html {overflow-y: scroll; /* Keeps page centred in all browsers regardless of content height */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

/* ------------------------*/ /* ---------->>> Global Styles <<<-----------*/ /* ------------------------*/


body 
    {
        background: url(images/bg.svg) repeat-x #f8f8f8;
        background-size: 8px 250px;
        color: #222;        
        font: normal 1.25rem/2rem 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif;
        padding:0; 
        margin: 0;
    }

a {color: #940902;}
a:hover {color: #333; text-decoration: underline;}
img  {border: none;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, blockquote {font-family: Georgia, serif; font-weight: normal; text-align: left;}
h2 {font-size: calc(2vw + 2rem); margin-bottom: 2rem; line-height: calc(2vw + 2rem);}   
a img { border: 0;}
img {
    height: auto; /* Make sure images are scaled correctly. */
    max-width: 100%; /* Adhere to container width. */
}

hr {visibility: hidden; clear: both;}
img.left {margin: .65rem 2rem 0 0; border: 5px solid white; box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #999; border-radius: 2px;}
.left {float: left;}
p.right {margin-bottom: 1rem; display: block; text-align: right; margin-right: 4rem;}
.bold {font-weight: bold;}
.alignleft {
    float:left;
    margin:5px 20px 20px 0;
}
a img.alignleft {
    float:left;
    margin:5px 20px 20px 0;
}       
/* ------------------------*/ /* ---------->>> Header Styles <<<-----------*/ /* ------------------------*/
header.header {
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 250px;
    background: url(images/logo.svg) no-repeat 6% 48% ;
    background-size: 300px 90px;
    border-top: 0px solid black;
    position: relative;

}
header.header h1 {display: none;}
header.header a {color: white; transition: all 0.2s; text-decoration: none; }
header.header ul {display: block;}
header.header ul li {display: inline-block; }
nav 
{
    box-sizing: content-box;
    position: absolute; 
    top: 170px; 
    right: 0px;  
    background: url(images/tab.svg) no-repeat top left; 
    background-size: 1600px 108px; 
    z-index: 99; 
    letter-spacing: .085em;
    padding-top: .75rem;    
}
nav ul li.first {margin-left: 120px; padding-left: .7rem;   }   
nav a {display: block; color: white;}
nav a:hover {color: #ccc; text-decoration: none;}
nav ul {
  display: block;
  padding-right: 3rem;
  height: 36px;
}
nav ul li 
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 1rem 1.5rem 1.5rem 1.5rem;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}
nav ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 67px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
}
nav ul li ul:first-child {border-top: 10px solid black;}
nav ul li ul li { 
  background: #7d2316; 
  border-bottom: 1px solid #741e12;
  display: block; 
  color: #fff;
 font-weight: normal; 
 font-size: .9em;
  width: 80%; display: block;
  padding: .75rem 1.75rem;
}
nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #000; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}
nav ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: .95;
  visibility: visible;
}
li.order {display: none;}
a.arrow {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: url(images/double-arrow.svg) no-repeat top right  #92321f; 
    background-size: contain; 
    padding:  0 1.5rem 0 1rem;  
    }
a.arrow:hover {background-color: black;}
#social {position: absolute; top: 55px; right: 5%; z-index: 99; display: block;}
#social li {padding: 0 0 0 0; margin: 1rem .75rem; display: inline-block; width: 58px; transition: all 0.5s ease;}
#social li:hover {transform: rotate(360deg);}

/* ------------------------*/ /* ---------->>> Main Structure<<<-----------*/ /* ------------------------*/
.main-column {  padding: 3em 0 1em 0; width:50%;}
.main-column, .sole-column {

    text-align: justify;
    max-width: 1000px;

}
.main-column, .side-column {display: inline-block;}

.sole-column {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 4em 0 2em 0;
    width:65%;
}
.side-column {
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 40%; 
    padding-left: 2rem;
}

.side-column img {margin-right: 0%;}
.side-column h3 {font: normal 1.5vw/2rem 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif; display: inline; }
.two-column {width: 90%; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}

/* ------------------------*/ /* ---------->>> Blog Styles <<<-----------*/ /* ------------------------*/
#primary {

    margin-top: 0;
    width:70%;
    max-width: 1100px;
    background-color: #fbfbfb;

    display: inline-block;

    border-right: 4px solid white;
}
.post-title, .post-title-mobile {font-size: 2rem; margin-bottom: 1rem; }
.post-title-mobile {display: none;}
.post-title a, .post-title-mobile a {text-decoration: none; padding-bottom: .35rem; color: #222;}
.post-title a:hover {color: #940902; border-bottom: 2px dotted black; }
.post { border-bottom: 4px solid white; padding: 2rem 4rem 1.5rem 4rem;}
.post p {text-align: justify; overflow: hidden;}
.comments {padding-bottom: 1rem; float: right;}
.pagination  {padding: 2rem 4rem; font-size: 1.5rem; text-align: left;}

.clearfix:after, .post-content:after, .single .post-content p:after, .comment-content:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
.wp-post-image
{
    width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    clear: left;
    margin: .5rem 0px 0px 0;
    border: 6px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
}
div.thumbdate 
{
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 100px; 
    padding-right: 2rem; 
    font-size: 1.15rem; 
    box-sizing: content-box; 
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;

}

.date {line-height: 1; width: 6.8rem; margin: .6rem 0 1rem 0;}
.day 
{
    float: left; 
    border-right: 2px solid #000; 
    padding-right: .15em ; 
    margin: 0 .15em 0 0; 
    font: 3em 'Times', serif; 
    color: #940902; 
    line-height: .75;
}
.year {font-size: .95em; }
.month 
{
    font-size: 1.15em; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    margin-top: .35em; 

}
.day, .year, .month {display: block; font-weight: bold; }
/* Blog sidebar */
#sidebar 
{
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 28%; 
    padding: 2rem; 
    margin-top: 1rem;   
    text-align: left;
}
#sidebar h3 {padding-bottom: .75rem; font-size: 2rem;}
#sidebar a {text-decoration: none; color: #840700;}
#sidebar a:hover {color: #000; }
#sidebar ul {line-height: 1;}
#sidebar ul li {padding: 2rem; }
#sidebar h3, #sidebar ul li {border-bottom: 2px dotted #ccc;}
.sidebardate {display: inline-block; float:left; margin-right: 1rem;}
.sidebarmonth {font-size: .95rem; text-transform: uppercase;}
.sidebarday {font-size: 1.55rem; color: #840700; margin-top: -.25rem; font-family: 'Times', serif}
.sidebarmonth, .sidebarday {display:  block; font-weight: bold;}
/*tab styles */
.divider {background: url(images/tab-bg.svg) repeat-x, linear-gradient(90deg, #fbfbfb 50%, #f4f4f4 50%) repeat-y;  background-size: 15px 47px, auto auto;   margin-top: -2em; padding-top: 47px; text-align: center;}
h2.tab 
{
    padding: .8em 4em 0em 1.65em; 
    font-size: 2em; 
    display: inline-block; 
    clear: both;
    color: white;  
    background: url(images/tab-reverse.svg) no-repeat top right; 
    background-size: 1600px 108px; 
    margin: 0; 

    z-index: 99;
}
h2.tab:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
  }
/* ------------------------*/ /* ---------->>> Homepage Styles <<<-----------*/ /* ------------------------*/
#menu 
{
    width: 100%; 
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-top: 6rem;   
    border: 4px solid white;    
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #ccc;
    background: url(images/food-display.jpg) no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover; 

}
#menu:hover {opacity: .9; transition: opacity .3s;}
#menu img {width: 100%; height: auto; }
#menu h2 {display: none;}

.deals {margin: 3rem 0 2rem 0;}
.deals h3 
{
    font-family: 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif; 
    font-weight: bold; 
}
.deals ul 
{
    background: url(images/connector.svg) no-repeat 1.5rem 30px; 
    background-size: 1px 200px; 
    list-style-type: none;
}
.deals ul li 
{
    padding: 0rem 0 1.6rem 4rem;
}
.deals ul li.silverware 
{
    background: url(images/icon-silverware.svg) no-repeat; 
}
.deals ul li.kids 
{
    background: url(images/icon-kids.svg) no-repeat; 
}
.deals ul li.punch 
{
    background: url(images/icon-double-punch.svg) no-repeat; 
}
.deals ul li.kids, .deals ul li.silverware, .deals ul li.punch 
{
    background-size: 50px 50px;
    background-position: 0 7px;
}
#browse {width: 100%; background: url(images/tab-bg.svg) repeat-x #f4f4f4; background-position: 0 0px; background-size: 15px 47px; padding-top: 57px;   margin-top: -4rem;}
h2.browse 
{
    display: inline-block; 
    padding: 1em 6em 1em 4em; 
    font-size: 1.25em; 
    color: white;  
    background: url(images/icon-menu.svg) no-repeat 1em .85em, url(images/tab-reverse.svg) no-repeat top right; 
    background-size: 47px 41px, 1600px 108px; 
    margin: 2rem 0 0 0;
}
#browse ul
{
    z-index: 99; 
    margin-top: -.5em;
}
#browse ul li 
{
    display: inline-block; 
    width: 16.6667%; 
    outline: 3px solid white;
}
#browse ul li a 
{
    display: block; 
    text-align: center;
    background: url(images/block-transparent.png) repeat-x;
    background-size: 10px 47px;
    background-position: bottom left;
    color: white; 
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 175px;
    border-bottom: 10px solid black;
}
#browse ul li a em
{       
    padding: 0rem .2rem .1rem.2rem; 
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
}
#browse ul li a:hover 
{color: #ccc; 
border-bottom: 10px solid #940902; 
    background: url(images/block.png) repeat-x;
    background-size: 10px 47px;
    background-position: bottom left;
    transition: border-bottom 0.5s ease, background 0.5s ease;
}
.pasta {background: url(images/browse-pasta.jpg);}
.pizzas {background: url(images/browse-pizza.jpg);}
.soups {background: url(images/browse-soups.jpg);}
.appetizers {background: url(images/browse-appetizers.jpg);}
.entrees {background: url(images/browse-entrees.jpg);}
.subs {background: url(images/browse-subs.jpg);}
.pasta, .pizzas, .soups, .appetizers, .entrees, .subs 
{
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-color: black; 
    background-size: cover; 
    height: 175px; 
    padding: 0em; 
}



/*Makes the thumb on the homepage scale with the paragraph*/
p.scaling-thumb {
    background: url(images/pizza-thumb-border.png), url(images/pizza-thumb.jpg); 
    overflow: hidden; 
    background-size: 9rem auto; 
    padding-left: 11rem; 
    background-position: bottom left, 0 7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.nowrap {white-space: nowrap;}

/* Force Metaslider Plugin to adhere to new styles */
.metaslider {overflow:hidden;}
.metaslider .caption-wrap {opacity: .9 !important;}
.caption {font-size: 2rem; 
        font-family: Georgia, serif; 
        color: white; 
        line-height: 2rem; 
        padding: 1.5rem 0 !important;
        text-align: center;}

#slider 
{
    background-image: url(http://alessiosrestaurant.ashleywalters.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/slider2-2000x561.jpg); 
    height: 435px; 
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-size: cover; 
    border-bottom: 40px solid black; 
    text-align: center; 
    margin-top: 3px;
}

#slider p 
{
        font-size: 2vw; 
        font-family: Georgia, serif; 
        color: white; 
        line-height: 1em; 
        background-color: black; 
        border-bottom: 0px solid white;
        opacity: .9;
        padding: .5em; 
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
}
#slider img {max-width: 20%; height: auto; margin-top: .5em;}
/* ------------------------*/ /* ---------->>> Footer Styles <<<-----------*/ /* ------------------------*/
footer.footer 
{
    border-top: 0px solid black;

    width: 100%;

    background: url(images/tab-bg.svg) repeat-x, url(images/brick.jpg) repeat top left; 
    background-position: 0 0px, top left; 
    background-size: 15px 47px, 1587px 397px; padding-top: 57px;
    background-color: #63140a;   
    color: white;
    padding: 0rem 0 0 0;

}
/*footer.footer h2:before {content: '\e0c8'; font-family: "Material Icons";  font-size: 2.75rem; vertical-align: inherit;}*/
footer.footer h2 {margin-bottom: 0; vertical-align: middle;
background: url(images/tab-bg.svg) repeat-x black; background-position: 0 0px; 
background-size: 15px 47px; padding: 1.5rem 2rem .75rem 2rem; font-size: 2rem; border-bottom: 3px solid #eee; }
footer.footer h3 {font-size: 2rem; font-family: 'Pragati Narrow', sans-serif; margin-bottom: .5rem; letter-spacing: .1rem;}
footer.footer ul+p {
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: black; 
    outline: 2px solid #eee;
    padding: 1.5rem 1rem; 
    margin-top: -10px; 
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
    color: #eee;
    letter-spacing: .05rem;
}
.locations {text-align: left; margin: 0 auto; width: 75%; }
footer.footer ul {text-align: center;  margin: 0rem auto 0 auto; padding-top: 0rem; width: 80%;}
footer.footer ul li {display: inline-block; margin: 2rem auto; width: 33%; padding: 1rem 0; 
vertical-align: top; line-height: 1.35; text-align: center; }
footer.footer ul li:nth-child(n+2) {border-left: 0px dotted #eee;}
p.location {background: url(images/icon-location.svg);  letter-spacing: .05rem;}
p.hours {background: url(images/icon-hours.svg);}
p.phone {background: url(images/icon-phone.svg); padding-bottom: 5px;   letter-spacing: .05rem;}
p.location, p.hours, p.phone {background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 26px; padding-left: 40px; background-position: 0 4px; margin-bottom: 1rem;}


/* ------------------------*/ /* ---------->>> Responsive Design <<<-----------*/ /* ------------------------*/
/*For large tablets*/
@media screen and (max-width: 1100px)  {
.post { padding: 2rem 2rem 1rem 2rem; width: 100%; }
.post h3 {font-size: 3vw;}
#primary {margin: 0 auto 0rem auto; width: 100%;  display: block; border: none; border-bottom: 4px solid white;}
#sidebar {width: 100%; display: block;  margin: 0 0 3rem 0; padding: 0;}
#sidebar ul {padding: 0 4rem;}
#sidebar ul li  {border: none;}
#sidebar ul li:nth-child(n+2) {border-top: 2px dotted #ccc;}
#sidebar h3:first-of-type {display: block; background: url(images/tab-bg.svg) repeat-x black; 
background-size: 15px 47px; padding: 2rem 2rem 1rem 2rem; 
font-size: 2rem; outline: 4px solid white; color: white; border: none; margin-bottom: 1rem;}
.pagination {padding: 1rem 2rem; }
.main-column {margin: 0 auto; padding: 2rem; width: 40%;}
.two-column {width: 100%;}
.side-column {width: 40%;}
.sole-column {width: 100%; margin: 2.5rem auto; padding: 1rem 3rem 0 3rem;}
.deals {width: 50%; margin: 2rem auto;}
.deals ul {background: none;}
header.header { background-position: 6% 40% ; padding-top: 48px;  height: 300px;}
nav {position: relative; display: block;  background-color: black; border-bottom: 4px solid white; padding: 1rem 1rem 2rem 1rem; }
nav ul {display: block; padding-right: 0;  width: 90%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;}
nav ul li.first {margin-left: 0px; padding-left: 0em;   }   
nav ul li {text-align: left;}
#slider {height: 300px;}
#slider p {font-size: 2.25vw; padding: .75em; margin-bottom: -1.5em;}
#slider img {margin-top: .5em; max-width: 15%; height: auto;}
#social {position: absolute; top: 95px; right: 5%; }
#social li {margin: 0em 0 0em 1em; width: 50px; }
.divider {background: url(images/tab-bg.svg) repeat-x #f4f4f4;}
h2.browse-menu {background-position: 1rem 1rem, top right; }
#menu { padding: 0em; margin: 10em auto 0 auto; }
h2.tab 
{
    padding-left: 1.5em; 
    font-size: 3.5vw; 
}
footer.footer ul {width: 100%;}
footer.footer ul li {width: 32%;}
}

/*For all other tablets*/
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {


.deals {width: 70%; }
.comments {display: none;}
.locations { padding: 0rem 5rem; width: 100%;}
h2.tab {display: block; background: url(images/tab-bg.svg) repeat-x black; background-position: 0 0px; background-size: 15px 47px; padding: 2rem 2rem 1rem 2rem; font-size: 2.25rem;}
.divider {background: none;}        
header.header {background: url(images/logo.svg) no-repeat center 40%; background-size: 250px 75px; border-top: 1px solid black; }
nav {font-size: .85em;}
nav ul {display: block; padding-right: 0;  padding-left: 0; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;}    
nav ul li.first {display: none; }   
nav ul li {  text-align: left;  margin-right: 0;  padding: 1em 1.5vw; }
nav ul li ul {top: 67px; width: 125px;} 
#social {width: 90%; text-align: center; margin: 90px auto 0 auto;}
#social li {outline: 0px solid purple; margin: 0; width: 50px;}
#social li:nth-child(2) {margin: 0em 1.25rem; }
a.arrow {display: none;}
.main-column {width: 100%;}
.sole-column {padding: 0rem 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;}
.side-column {width: 100%; padding: 1rem;}
.deals {width: 100%; margin: 0 auto;}
#menu {margin: -2rem 0 2rem 0;}
p.scaling-thumb {background: none;  padding: 0 .5rem;}
#primary {background-color: #f4f4f4;}
#sidebar ul {padding: 0 1rem;}
.post-title-mobile {display: block; border-bottom: 2px dotted #666; padding-bottom: .75rem;}
.post-title-mobile a:hover {color: #940902; }
.post-title {display: none;}
.post p {overflow: initial;}
#browse {background: none; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
h2.browse {background: url(images/icon-menu.svg) no-repeat 1rem center, url(images/tab-bg.svg) repeat-x black; 
background-size: 47px 41px, 15px 47px; 
display: block; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 2rem 2rem 2rem 5rem;}
#browse ul li {width: 33.33%; padding: 0; margin-top: -.5rem; }
#browse ul {margin: 0;}
#browse ul li a em {font-size: calc(2vw + .5rem);}
.locations {padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 2rem; width: 300px;}
footer.footer ul {margin: 0; padding: 0; }
footer.footer ul li {max-width: 100%; width: 100%;  border-right: 5vw solid black; border-left: 5vw solid black; background: url(images/left-arrow-bg.png) no-repeat center left; 
margin: 0; }
footer.footer ul li:nth-child(n+2) {border-top: 2px dotted #eee;  border-right: 5vw solid black; border-left: 5vw solid black;}
footer.footer ul li p {font-size: 1.25rem;}
footer.footer h2 {display: block;}

}
```

index.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * @package Frank
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php 
    echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=12]"); 
?>
<div id="content" class="home">
   <div class="sole-column">
   <h2><span class="nowrap">Good People.</span> <span class="nowrap">Good Food.</span></h2>       
    <p class="scaling-thumb">
     Family-owned and operated, Alessio's Restaurant & Pizzeria has been part of the Metro Atlanta community for over 20 years. 
     We pride ourselves on serving you the finest pizza, calzones, pasta, and sandwiches this side of the Big Apple. 
     Our authentic New York style pizza and Italian classics are made from scratch with fresh ingredients and hand-tossed dough. 
     We served all our food with a smile so come on over and see us soon.     
    </p>
   </div>
     <h2 class="browse">Browse Our Menu</h2>
   <div id="browse" >
   <ul><!-- The li tags below must have no space between them or gaps will appear   <img alt="image" src="wp-content/themes/Frank-master/images/pizza-footer.jpg" class="left" />-->
    <li class="pizzas"><a href="#" ><em>Pizza</em></a>
    </li><li class="pasta"><a href="#" ><em>Pasta</em></a>
    </li><li class="entrees"><a href="#" ><em>Entrees</em></a>
    </li><li class="subs"><a href="#" ><em>Subs & Paninis</em></a>
    </li><li class="soups"><a href="#" ><em>Soups & Salads</em></a>
    </li><li class="appetizers"><a href="#" ><em>Appetizers</em></a>
    </li>
   </ul>
   </div>
    <div class="two-column">
    <div class="main-column deals">
   <h2>Hot Deals</h2>
   <ul>
   <li class="silverware">
    <h3>Monday</h3>
    $3.00 off a 16" cheese pizza & $5.00 off a pitcher of domestic beer
   </li>
   <li class="kids">
    <h3>Tuesday</h3>
    Kids eat free (with one adult purchase of $10 or more)
   </li>
   <li class="punch">
   <h3>Wednesday</h3>
   Double punch day
   </li>
   </ul>

    </div>
  <div class="side-column">
   <div id="menu">
    <h2>Download our Menu</h2>
    <a href="#"><img src="wp-content/themes/Frank-master/images/download-menu.svg" alt="Icon of a spoon and a folding menu" /></a>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div>
<hr>
  <h2 class="tab"> Latest Alessio's News</h2>
  <div class="divider">    
 <div id="primary">    
   <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php while ( have_posts() ) : ?>
   <?php the_post(); ?>    
    <article class="post clearfix clear" id="p<?php the_ID(); ?>">      
    <div class="alignleft thumbdate">
      <div class="date">
       <em class="day"><?php the_time('d'); ?></em><div class="month-year"><em class="month"><?php the_time('M'); ?></em><em class="year"><?php the_time('Y'); ?></em></div>
      </div>
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>     </div> 
    <h2 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
      <section class="post-content clearfix">
       <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </section>
      <p class="comments"><a href="<?php comments_link(); ?>">Comment<img alt="image" src="wp-content/themes/Frank-master/images/icon-comments.svg" height="22" width="32" /></a></p>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
    <?php comments_template(); ?>
    <p class="pagination">
    <?php global $wp_query;

$big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $wp_query->max_num_pages
) );
?>
            </p>    
</div>
<aside id="sidebar">
<h3 class="widget-title">Recent Posts</h3>
<ul>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=10' ); ?>
 <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>
 <li><div class="sidebardate"><span class="sidebarday"><?php the_time('d'); ?></span><span class="sidebarmonth"><?php the_time('M'); ?></span></div>
<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
<?php 
endwhile;
wp_reset_postdata();
?>
</ul>
</aside>

    </div></div>    
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please  specify the exact screen size, cause I dont find any issues with it, here is the screenshot : https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/3086452/a42b5be1692b547deb6f9117d1f3a1bb

Comment: Every screen size is wrong in Chrome on my machine. The wide width is not showing the headers correctly, and the responsive css is being ignored when sized down.

Comment: Have you checked your chorme version, is it updated?

Comment: According to Chrome I have the latest version: "Google Chrome is up to date
Version 63.0.3239.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)"

Comment: Ok, let me check that again as I am not able to see the issues you are having.

Comment: I just cleared my cached and it fixed it somehow. Not sure what's going on there, but thanks for letting me know it was working for you!

Comment: Its Ok, I think, Your browser had stored cache...

Comment: Fooled by the cache again :). You could try opening up your developer tools and in the settings check "Disable browser cache (while devTools is open)". It should help while developing.